# Как лучше организовать роутинг для ссылок определенного формата?

Tags: php, laravel

Имеются ссылки вида:
`site.ru/page/all` - Тут список всех страниц
`site.ru/page/1-news-name.html`

Как лучше всего организовать роутинг для такого вида ссылок?

Answer (score 1):

[Документация для Laravel 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing).

#### Допущения в ответе

Предполагается наличие модели для вашей таблицы с названием `Page`.
Предполагается наличие двух шаблонов:

- `/resources/views/page/all.blade.php`
- `/resources/views/page/view.blade.php`

#### Вместе с контроллером

Файл `routes.php`

```
Route::get('/page/all', [
    'as' => 'all',
    'uses' => 'YourController@showAll'
]);

Route::get('/page/{id}-{slug}.html', [
    'as' => 'page',
    'uses' => 'YourController@showPage'
])->where([
    // Валидация параметров
    'id' => '[0-9]+',
    'slug' => '[a-z-]+'
]);
```

Файл `YourController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Список всех страниц
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function showAll()
    {
        return view('page.all', ['pages' => Page::all()]);
    }
    /**
     * Определенная страница
     * @param int $id
     * @param string $slug
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function showPage($id, $slug)
    {
        return view('page.view', ['page' => Page::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
}
```

В методе `showPage()` контроллера можно искать одновременно по `id` и по `slug`.
Делайте, как вам больше нравится.

#### Без контроллера

Файл `routes.php`

```
Route::get('/page/all', function () {
    return 'Список всех страниц';
});

Route::get('/page/{id}-{slug}.html', function ($id, $slug) {
    return "Страница {$id} с ключевым словом {$slug}.";
});
```